# Font-size Initial CSS value for html heading tags

Tags: html, css

I want to reset the font-sze of H1 tags to the default.. according to W3 schools:

> The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default
>   value.

Now when I apply it, the text appears smaller than the default (no CSS) value...

Example here:

http://jsbin.com/cifedofoci/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I believe `initial` sets the style to the browser's default value pre any useragent stylesheets. So in this case all text has the same size and the useragent stylesheet creates the sizes you're used to, however by setting it to initial you're going back to before the useragent stylesheet font-size change are being applied.

Comment: @j08691: The initial value has nothing to do with user agent defaults. The initial value for every property is defined within its propdef in the spec. It's the value that becomes the specified value for when there exist no declarations for a property - not even user agent default declarations.

Comment: @BoltClock I just read your comment three times and it still didn't make any sense

Comment: @j08691: A UA default stylesheet is up to the vendor to decide for itself - browser A might have its own reasons for choosing to make h1s larger than browser B, and browser C might have *no* UA defaults for h1 - in which case the font-size of h1 in C is its initial value. This initial value is defined in the spec as "medium". Furthermore, an explicit CSS rule `h1 { font-size: initial; }` requires all browsers to set the font-size of h1 elements to medium.

Comment: @j08691: There is virtually no reason to use the initial keyword in an author stylesheet. The concept of an initial value is only there to ensure every element (including unknown elements) has a specified value for every single property, regardless of whether or not the UA has specified defaults. The revert keyword was recently introduced allowing you to actually revert a value to UA defaults, but how long until we get to use it cross-browser is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

The 'default' value is specific to each browser, it's not related to the tag or style. For most browsers the default value is 16px, while h1 sets the size to 32px.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out this issue as well, and I found an explanation I want to share here;

> Declaring display: initial is equivalent to display: inline. It won’t evaluate to display: block regardless of what type of element you apply it to. That’s because initial resets to the initial value for the property, not the element; inline is the default value for the display property.

So to say, the 'initial' value is the default value for the "Property", not a tag.
An h1 element/tag, without any styling applied to it, has 32px(2em) font-size, and this value is derived from browser's settings when we talk about font-size property inside a h1 element, but font-size property by itself has 16px value overall throughout the page.